# How do I display category names instead of point.y in Highcharts scatterplot?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

First, my apologies for the messy script. I am restricted to using a notepad due to limited resource where I am.

When I graph a scatterplot, the tooltip returns `point.y` value in numeric terms. I would like to show strings such as `one`, `two`, `Very Berry` instead of numeric values by using category names in yAxis.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
  </head>
<body>
<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 100%; max-width: 100%; margin: 0 auto"></div>
<script>

Highcharts.chart('container', {

    chart: {
        type: 'scatter',
        zoomType: 'xy'
    },

    title: {
        text: 'Some title'
    },

    xAxis: {
        title: {
            enabled: true,
            text: 'Date'
        },

    type: 'datetime',
        labels:
        {
            formatter: function () {
                    return Highcharts.dateFormat("%b %Y", this.value);
                }
        }

    },

    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: 'Rank goes to 10000'
        },

    categories: [
                'One',
                'Two',
                'Three',
                'Four',
                'Five',
                'Six',
                'Seven',
                'Eight',
                'Nine',
                'Ten'
            ],
    type: 'category'
    },

    legend: {
        layout: 'vertical',
        align: 'right',
        verticalAlign: 'top',
        x: 0,
        y: 0,
        floating: false,
        backgroundColor: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.legendBackgroundColor) || '#FFFFFF',
        borderWidth: 1
    },

    plotOptions: {
        scatter: {
            marker: {
                radius: 6,
        fillOpacity:0.3,
                states: {
                    hover: {
                        enabled: true,
                        lineColor: 'rgb(100,100,100)'
                    }
                }
            },
            tooltip: { 
                headerFormat: '<b>{series.name}</b><br>',
                pointFormat: 'Rank: {point.y} <br>Date: {point.x:%b %e, %Y}'
            }
        }
    },

    series: [{
        name: 'Beer',
        data: [
        [Date.UTC(2018, 2, 23), 1],
        [Date.UTC(2009, 5, 22), 2],
        [Date.UTC(2018, 6, 1), 3],
        [Date.UTC(2009, 9, 11), 4],
        [Date.UTC(2018, 11, 30), 5],
        [Date.UTC(2009, 10, 10), 6],
        [Date.UTC(2013, 12, 1), 7],
        [Date.UTC(2015, 4, 6), 8],
        [Date.UTC(2005, 2, 1), 9],
        [Date.UTC(2010, 1, 1), 10]

        ]
    },{
    name: 'Wine',
        color: 'rgba(223, 83, 83, .9)',
        data: [
            [Date.UTC(2012, 1, 1), 8]
          ]
        }
    ]
    });

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `tooltip.pointFormat` [Api Doc](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.scatter.tooltip.pointFormat), you can do what you are looking for

```
var yCategories = [
  'One',
  'Two',
  'Three',
  'Four',
  'Five',
  'Six',
  'Seven',
  'Eight',
  'Nine',
  'Ten'
];
...
  tooltip: {
    //headerFormat: '<b>{series.name}</b><br>',
    //pointFormat: 'Rank: {point.y} <br>Date: {point.x:%b %e, %Y}',
    pointFormatter: function() {
      var formatedDate = new Date(this.x).toLocaleDateString("en-US")
      return '<b>' + this.series.name + '</b><br>' +
        'Rank: ' + yCategories[this.y - 1] + '<br>Date: ' + formatedDate
    }
  }
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/core972/fgyscwdz/)

Comment: Thanks! I will go check it out when I get to work : )

Comment: One more question -- how do I change the opacity of the circle-markers? I am using `fillOpacity:0.3` as described in the documentation, but I have been unsuccessful.

Comment: scatter doesn't have `fillOpacity` only bubble and area have this option, instead use the color option like you did in the second serie `color: 'rgba(223, 83, 83, .9)'`